# Yocto Error : Could not inherit file classes/qt6-cmake.bbclass

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm currently trying to 'boot 2 qt'

I add layers, at "bblayers.conf"
like this.

/yocto/kirkstone/meta-boot2qt/meta-boot2qt \

and also set machine at "local.conf"

when I try to bitbake, the error occurs like this

Input : bitbake b2qt-embedded-qt6-image

Output: ERROR: ParseError at /home/seame-fablab/yocto/kirkstone/meta-boot2qt/meta-boot2qt/recipes-qt/boot2qt-addons/qdb_git.bb:36: Could not inherit file classes/qt6-cmake.bbclass
ERROR: Parsing halted due to errors, see error messages above

how to solve the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its likely you are simply missing the layer where qt6-cmake.bbclass belongs to.

Its hard to say if you missed cloning it, or just adding it to your `bblayers.conf` since you didnt really specify how you actually cloned the repos, but the README for meta-boot2qt suggests you use `repo` for such task, which should've taken care of that for you.

For example, using

```
mkdir ~/mybuilddir
cd ~/mybuilddir/
repo init -u git://code.qt.io/yocto/boot2qt-manifest -m 6.5.xml
repo sync
```

would get you a structure like this:

```
$ tree -L 2                                                                                                                        
.
├── setup-environment.sh -> sources/meta-boot2qt/scripts/setup-environment.sh
└── sources
    ├── meta-boot2qt
    ├── meta-freescale
    ├── meta-freescale-3rdparty
    ├── meta-intel
    ├── meta-mingw
    ├── meta-openembedded
    ├── meta-qt6
    ├── meta-raspberrypi
    ├── meta-tegra
    ├── meta-toradex-bsp-common
    ├── meta-toradex-nxp
    ├── poky
    └── templates -> meta-boot2qt/meta-boot2qt-distro/conf/templates/default
```

And the class you are missing is located at:

```
./sources/meta-qt6/classes/qt6-cmake.bbclass
```

Now, if you for some reason dont want to use `repo` and would like to manually clone the required layers, you are also welcome to do that, you just  need to clone meta-qt6:

```
git clone https://code.qt.io/cgit/yocto/meta-qt6.git/
```

and add it to your bblayers.conf

```
bitbake-layers add-layer <path-to-meta-qt6-layer-you-just-cloned>
```

Comment: Thank you for great solution.
I donwloaded meta-qt6 layer, and add it to bblayers.conf

Now there's new error like below

ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'b2qt-embedded-qt6-image'

Comment: Actually, When I type bitbake core-image-minimal,there's no error. But the error 'ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'b2qt-embedded-qt6-image' appears only when I type bitbake b2qt-embedded-qt6-image

Comment: What bitbake is telling you is that from all the recipes it parsed, none of them were able to PROVIDE `b2qt-embedded-qt6-image`, next step would be to find which recipe should be providing that (typically the recipe name == PROVIDES, unless otherwise specified), the recipe for that image is in:
`./sources/meta-boot2qt/meta-boot2qt-distro/recipes-qt/images/b2qt-embedded-qt6-image.bb`
which means that now you are missing the layer where such recipe is coming from, doing the same as above (`bitbake add-layer`) but with the path to ./sources/meta-boot2qt/meta-boot2qt-distro/ should fix it

Comment: You see no error when building `core-image-minimal` because that recipe is in the `meta` directory which is in your `bblayers.conf` by default, hence bitbake is able to find a provider for it with no issues